# Generate a stars object from tabular spatial temporal data?

Tags: r, sf, stars

I have tabular data with columns `longitude`, `latitude`, `time`, and `intensity`, like so:

```r
library(lubridate)

## mock example data
ex <- tibble(longitude = 1:10, 
             latitude = 10:1, 
             date = today() : (today() + 9), 
             intensity = rnorm(10))
```

In reality, it is a collection of ~ 230 compressed tab-separated text files,  10 MB each, in the above format.

I am trying to go from this tabular representation (e.g. reading this data with `readr::read_tsv()`) to a `stars` object (eventually/ideally a `stars_proxy` object, given the data size).

One thing I've considered is converting to an `st` object first:

```
star1 <- ex %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), 
         crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_as_stars()
```

but this creates a `stars` object with only one `dimension`, which is a geometry.  Since I have a point geometry, I'd rather have this as `x` and `y` dimensions in the 4326 (WGS84) CRS, and I'd like `time` to be a dimension.  I can coerce the dimension (I think), with:

```
star2 <- st_set_dimensions(star1, 1, star1$date, "date")
```

though I still see only 1 listed dimension:

```
star2
stars object with 1 dimensions and 2 attributes
attribute(s):
     date          intensity      
 Min.   :18332   Min.   :-1.3239  
 1st Qu.:18334   1st Qu.:-0.9127  
 Median :18336   Median :-0.1671  
 Mean   :18336   Mean   :-0.1405  
 3rd Qu.:18339   3rd Qu.: 0.4975  
 Max.   :18341   Max.   : 1.0076  
dimension(s):
         from to offset delta refsys point values
geometry    1 10  18332     1     NA  date   NULL
```

So, given data in this tabular format, how do I generate a proper a `stars` object (ideally `stars_proxy` object), with proper x,y, and time `dimension` attributes?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your question to ask a single question.

Comment: Thanks! I've revised my question accordingly!

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to directly define the correct dimensions:

```
st_as_stars(ex, dims = c("longitude", "latitude", "date"))

stars object with 3 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
                Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. NA's
intensity  -1.193894 -0.4824627 0.04344971 0.09380003 0.552871 1.687245  990
dimension(s):
          from to offset delta refsys point values x/y
longitude    1 10    0.5     1     NA    NA   NULL [x]
latitude     1 10   10.5    -1     NA    NA   NULL [y]
date         1 10  19241     1     NA    NA   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Not full answer but

```
ex_star <- st_as_stars(ex)
```

will create a stars with the first two columns from the tibble as the first two dimensions of the stars, so make sure you pass a tibble with the correct arrangement of columns. There is a `dimensions` argument which I honestly till now I thought that giving a number would tell `st_stars` to keep adding columns as dimensions but I tested it and does not seem to work.